# PostgreSQL: text fields: how to index them?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql-9.3

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 (i can't update to 9.4); in some tables of my DB I have columns of text type; I need this because I need to store some huge data (also HTML content)
Moreover I need to do some searchs on these fields
What is the best way to full index these fields in order to improve search performances?
Since I'm suing hibernate I may consider to use Hibernate Search too....but before to modify the code and introduce it, I'd love to see if by using some PostgreSQL index I can improve search performances

Any suggestion is welcome

Thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have much options here. You'll have to use some form of text indexing, and they will all require the code to be changed.

With Hibernate Search, Hibernate will create indexes and maintain them, but that could add complexity to your app. Of course, the code for using this is completely different than for normal queries.

You could also take a look at [Postgre's full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch.html), where indexing will be done by database instead of Hibernate which is simpler than first option. Downside is that you will have to use native queries for full text searches (maybe you could extend Postgres dialect, not sure), but if it a limited use case it might not be a problem if you consider the benefit. And, you will tie your code to PostgreSQL which generally is not a good approach.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing...to tie the code to Postgres doesn't seem to me good...but it's sure simpler than introduce hibernate search, change the queries, test all again and put it in production (this scares me really a lot). I'll give a look to the link you gave me...